# Insert to table when surrogate key is being used

Tags: mysql, database, insert, mariadb

I have two tables:

Table 1 is:

- `product_id (INT 11)` - PK, Autoincrement
- `category (INT 11)` - Index, FK to `Table2.category_id`
- `product (VARCHAR 255)`

Table 2 is:

- `category_id (INT11)` - PK, Autoincrement
- `category_name (VARCHAR 255)`

Now, when adding a new product to table 1, I need to `INSERT` both category and product. But, category is a surrogate key, that relates to `Table2.category_id` column (each category has a column), meaning that when I'm inserting, I don't really know the `category_id`, just the `category_name`.

Any idea on how to make this work in an efficient way?

Or should I just give up surrogate keys and go full on to natural keys?

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow.  If you know the category to which the product belongs, then what is the issue here?

Comment: I know the category, but I don't know the category_id (unless I query the Table2, of course). And Table1 only accepts INT 11, because is linking to Table 2. I don't know the `category_id`, just the name.

Comment: So you're saying you know the text `category_name` but not the `category_id`?  This seems unusal.  Typically your app (e.g. PHP) would be dealing with `category_id` behind the scenes, so this would be available.

Comment: Exactly... is it? I would think that the situation would be very usual when setting multiple tables and using surrogate keys, but I have no experience whatsoever... Would you have any suggestion to deal with it? I have plenty of tables set up this way.

Comment: I can give you an answer, but it feels wrong to me.

Comment: I thought it would be better to use a surrogate key as a foreign key because they would be less prone to errors... but I truly have no idea on how to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a new product, but you only know the `category_name`, but not the `category_id`, then we try doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (category, product)
SELECT category_id, 'new product'
FROM table2
WHERE category_name = 'some category';
```

This feels like bad design to me, for a number of reasons.  First, presumably your app (e.g. PHP) would be dealing with the `category_id` under the hood, *not* the `category_name`.  So, ideally you should not have to query `table2` to make this insert work.  Another issue here is it might be possible for two or more categories to happen to have the same name (but a different `category_id`).  It is always better to work directly with the primary key if possible.

Comment: Now, that looks perfect. Why would that feel wrong to you? I'm programing with Python Flask.

Comment: I keep thinking of a PHP app where you have the `category_id` on tap, _not_ the `category_name`.

Comment: I'm designing a form in HTML, so in the front end, `category_name` is being used (not `id`). When submitting the form (to `INSERT` into the database), I have only the name...

Comment: actually `category_name` is unique, so the second case is not an issue...

Comment: Right...but let's say you were using a select box for that.  Then the keys would be `category_id` and the values would be `category_name`.  That is, you'd have the `category_id` on the UI side already.  Maybe this isn't possible for your UI for some reason.

Comment: This is why I'm bringing this up...it's rather unusual to do an insert the way you are asking.

Comment: Got it, I'll keep this in mind and try to fix the issue having the surrogate key already on the front end... thanks a lot for the input.

Comment: Precede with `INSERT IGNORE INTO categories (category_name) VALUE ('some category')` for the case when that category is not yet in the table.